# Trigger Status 'unknown' in Allure report

Tags: java, testng, allure

I'm using TestNG with Allure.

Throwing **org.testng.SkipException** will trigger status **skipped** (gray color) in the report:

```
if (DateUtils.dayOfMonth() < data.getTagDesMonatsAb()) {
    throw new SkipException("Der Test wird nur ab dem " + data.getTagDesMonatsAb() + ". des Monats ausgeführt.");
}
```

But how can I make the have status **unknown** (pink color)?

Answer (score 0):

My example will be on Java : how to set unknow(pink status) to Step

Allure.getLifecycle().stopStep();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).